# Mercurial ветки

Tags: mercurial

Добрый день.
Вопрос к знатокам Mercurial.
Есть рабочая ветка. В ней находятся файлы: 1, 2, 3.
Допустим нужно изменить файл 2. При этом изменяется файл 3.
Хотелось бы сохранить файл 3 локально, допустим в новой ветке, а изменения в файле 2 отправить на сервер.
Как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Возможно ли при слиянии веток вручную выбирать файлы, которые я хочу слить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опишу идею, а Вы по Вашим обстоятельствам применяйте.

Вначале сохраним в два файла дифы (эти файлы лучше сохранить отдельно,  не в рабочем каталоге)

```
hg diff 2 > my2.txt
hg diff 3 > my3.txt
```

теперь откатываем изменения

```
hg revert -a
```

создаем  на базе текущей ветки новую

```
hg ...
```

импортируем изменения с третьего файла

```
hg import --no-commit my3.txt
```

теперь можно посмотреть, проверить и закоммитить

```
hg commit ...
```

переключаемся назад на предыдущую ветку. и импортируем изменения

```
hg import --no-commit my2.txt
```

и можно продолжить работу - закоммитить и отправить  на сервер.

Comment: Спасибо. Вроде разобрался